# Can i insert data in an AUTOINCREMENT Field?

Tags: php, mysql

Simple like itself . I want an autoincrement field , but sometimes i must have repeated id's in some fields that i must set by hand.

Is there any problem to do that with an AUTOINCREMENT Field in Mysql , using PHP? (consistency , ... )

Comment: This smells of bad database design

Comment: It's not the primary key of this table.

Comment: You can't have an (automatic) autoincrement field in mysql that is not the primary key

Comment: @AD7six thanks, my mysql knowledge have some dust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can set autoincrement fields manually, the index will continue counting up from that number on (except if the id was smaller than the current ai index)
2. Autoincrement fields are unique so you have to be very careful when setting an ai field manually
3. Autoincrement fields in general shouldn't be set manually. If you post your use case maybe we could help you work out a better solution

Comment: I only wanna save time checking the max id of that field before insert , but i think i'll must do it anyway

Comment: you could use php's uniqid to generate ids [http://php.net/manual/de/function.uniqid.php] That would save you a select if it doesn't matter whether the ids are consecutive...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your php structure, you could replace:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name, incr)
VALUES ('hello', {$incr}) # using retrieved data
```

with

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name, incr)
SELECT 'hello', incr
FROM (  SELECT (incr + 1) AS incr
        FROM table_name
        ORDER BY incr DESC
        UNION
        SELECT 1) AS h
LIMIT 1
```

Basicly it would just check the highest `incr` value in your table, or give it 1 to start with. This would only require one MySQL call, and would speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a composite primary key (2 or more columns to create the primary key). One column could be autoincrement, the other your "repeated id". Either way, this ensures each row has a unique key.