# SQL: What would happen if, hypothetically, an out of place number was added to the unique identifier column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Lets think of it this way, say I have a table called "names" in MYSQL like so:

```
id| name
1 | Bob
2 | Sally
3 | Anne
```

Where "id" is a unique identifier for the table, and auto-increments with every addition of a row.

Say I somehow managed to throw in a row with an id that is completely out of place in the order, like so:

```
id| name
1 | Bob
2 | Sally
3 | Anne
20| John
```

Would the rows following the random row continue from the new id 20? (e.g next row added has id 21), or would they still continue from id 3? (e.g next row added has id 4)

Has this happened in SQl before?

Comment: Well I do not know about MySQL but in SQL SERVER, auto increment column values cannot be inserted/updated.

Comment: you can insert ids in MySQL by default and it will continue incrementing from the greatest number so 21 would be next

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503141/can-i-insert-data-in-an-autoincrement-field

Answer (score 3):

They will continue with 21, which prohibits duplicates. Otherwise you would have a problem when you reach 19 and the next inserted row should become 20, which is already there.

By the way it is not complicated to insert such a row. Just provide a specific value on `INSERT` instead of leaving out the auto-increment column or handing over `NULL`.

Unless you set the next-autoincrement value manually, MySQL does everything to assure that one does not run into conflicts. So if you insert a big value, it saves this+1 as next autoincrement value.

Answer (score 0):

To see what the next auto increment for mysql table will be, use

SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename';

There you will have **Auto_increment** column which says what is the next auto increment value. For the sake of test and curiosity I have conducted the following test:

I have created the table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `num` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Then I have conducted following queries:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`,`num`) VALUES (NULL,1);
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`,`num`) VALUES (NULL,2);
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`,`num`) VALUES (NULL,3);
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`,`num`) VALUES (50,4);
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`,`num`) VALUES (NULL,5);
```

Output is as follows:

```
mysql> select * from `test`;
+----+------+
| id | num  |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  2 |    2 |
|  3 |    3 |
| 50 |    4 |
| 51 |    5 |
+----+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which means, that after you insert your custom value, Auto_increment also gets incremented. Then I have executed one more query:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`,`num`) VALUES (100,6);
```

And after that status is as follows

```
mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'test';
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| test | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    6 |           2730 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |   8388608 |            101 | 2014-02-26 22:12:32 | NULL        | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can see that next auto increment value is going to be 101, which means that MySQL automatically adjusts to the inserted values.

Let me know what you think.